# I have 2 SSD's with different speeds

Tags: ssd

As the title says, I have 2 SSD's which have different speeds, 1 is only 270 MB/s Read and 165 MB/s Write (Sata II), the other is 535 MB/s Read and 320 MB/s Write (Sata III).

Windows 10 is currently installed on the Sata II SSD, My question is, would keeping  Windows 10 on the Sata II drive slow down programs launched from the Sata III Drive (Basically would it bottleneck the speed of the Sata III)?

Answer (score 1):

It could, but it probably won't.

If the programs on your SATA III SSD depend on other programs or libraries on the SATA II SSD, it could be slowed down to the SATA II's lower bandwidth, albeit only temporarily for as long as it takes to load that info into RAM.

However, for anything relating to the program itself, it'll run at the full SATA III speeds.

e.g:
If you have Anno 2070 and Steam on your SATA III SSD, but UPlay on your SATA II SSD, you'll find this situation:

1. Steam loads quickly
2. Steam loads up UPlay slowly
3. UPlay loads up Anno 2070 quickly

Your bottleneck would be on step 2, because UPlay is booting from the slower drive.

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought I was going to have to re-install Windows on the SATA III SSD, you saved me hours!

Comment: I still recommend reinstalling Windows on the SATA III SSD, just because then Windows itself will run faster. Your boot times will drop by a few seconds. How much this matters to you, I dunno, but it'd be worth it to me.

Comment: Alright, I might do that anyway, I'll see how K7AAY's solutions go, if I don't really see much of a performance issue then i'll probably keep Windows on the SATA II SSD. Thanks for the info :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

A) Your swap file and page file are on the slower drive. Every time Windows needs to dump files out of memory into swap, or read from swap back into memory, it's working at SATA II speeds. This can be addressed by moving the [swap file](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/is-it-possible-to-move-swapfile-sys-to-a-different-volume.34544/) and [page file](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-move-page-file-in-windows-10-to-another-disk/) from the slower to the faster drive.

B) Windows itself needs to load and unload its own files in the course of normal operations, or when an app makes a call to an [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) not in memory. I have no fix for this other than reinstalling Windows to a faster drive, or adding more memory so there's room for more Microsoft bloat. Memory's cheap.

Comment: Yeah, I have 32GB RAM (DDR4 @3200MHz) so allocating more memory isn't an issue, As for the swap file and page file I will change them to use the SATA III SSD instead of the SATA II